# Why are scripts given .phtml extension while working with zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Why are scripts given .phtml extension while working with zend framework?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `.phtml` extension applies only to view files as far as I can tell.

[Matthew Weier O'Phinney](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/MVC+View+Integration?focusedCommentId=21232#comment-21232) gives these reasons why he proposed that `.phtml` be used for views:

> I actually chose .phtml as (a) most apache configurations specify it as an alternate extension associated with the PHP engine, (b) most IDEs and text editors will identify .phtml as PHP + HTML for syntax highlighting, and (c) it visually separates template scripts from other PHP files in the directory tree.

So it's not much of a deal; it just makes it clearer that view files are the ones that largely comprise PHP interspersed in HTML templates for your applications. And as he said in point (b), most IDEs and editors recognize `.phtml` files so you shouldn't run into trouble dealing with them.

Comment: you can actually make your view scripts whatever extension you prefer if you register the extension to apache and your editor knows how to read it.

Answer (score 1):

To quote Mathew Weier O'Phinney, the person who propsed the use of .phtml:

> Suffixes are a developer preference, really; you don't need to use .tpl with Smarty, nor .php with Zend_View. I actually chose .phtml as (a) most apache configurations specify it as an alternate extension associated with the PHP engine, (b) most IDEs and text editors will identify .phtml as PHP + HTML for syntax highlighting, and (c) it visually separates template scripts from other PHP files in the directory tree.